# Adding to a dict using a list of key strings as path

Tags: python, dictionary, path, key

I have the following dict:

```
aDict = {
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c1" : {},
            "c2" : {},
        }
    }
}
```

a second dict:

```
aSecondDict = { 
    "d1" : {},
    "d2" : {},
    "d3" : {},
}
```

and a "path" tuple:

```
path = ( "a", "b", "c2" )
```

I now want to add the second dict to the first at the path provided by the tuple:

```
aResultDict = {
    "a" : {
        "b" : {
            "c1" : {},
            "c2" : {
                "d1" : {},
                "d2" : {},
                "d3" : {},
            },
        }
    }
}
```

What is the pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Could you please fix your dictionaries

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `reduce`<sup>1</sup> to get the dictionary and `dict.update` to put the new stuff in there:

```
reduce(lambda d,key: d[key],path,aDict).update(aSecondDict)
```

You can even get a little more clever if you want:

```
reduce(dict.__getitem__,path,aDict).update(aSecondDict)
```

I suppose it should be noted that the two approaches are slightly different.  The latter forces `aDict` to only contain more dictionaries (or `dict` subclasses) whereas the former allows for anything which has a `__getitem__` method to be in `aDict`.  [As noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300309/adding-to-a-dict-using-a-list-of-key-strings-as-path#comment23335068_16300379), you could also use:

```
reduce(dict.get,path,aDict).update(aSecondDict)
```

However, this version will raise an `AttributeError` if you try to traverse a "link" in the path which is non-existent rather than a `KeyError` so I don't like it quite as much.  This method also enforces that every value along the path is a `dict` or `dict` subclass.

<sup><sup>1</sup>`reduce` is a builtin for python2.x.  Starting at python2.6 it is also available as `functools.reduce`.  Code which wants to be compatible with python3.x should try to use `functools.reduce` as the builtin is removed in python3.x</sup>

Comment: or `reduce(dict.get, path, d)`

Comment: @jamylak -- Right.  The initializer always goes last.  Thanks.

Comment: Also if OP wants a copy he can just use `copy.deepcopy` and then do this

Comment: @jamylak -- I think I prefer `dict.__getitem__` to `dict.get` as the former will raise a `KeyError` when path is bad but the latter will raise a `AttributeError` (I think) which seems less helpful.

Comment: well a common python idiom is `max(d, key=d.get)`, do you write it like `max(d, key=d.__getitem__)`?

Comment: @jamylak -- That's marginally different.  In that case, it is impossible to get a `KeyError`.

Comment: @jamylak -- I've never made any guarantees about my sanity :-)