# Python: use *args as dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to figure out how to take a list of dictionaries:

```
some_list = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2}}, {'a':3, 'b':{'c':4}}, {'a':5, 'b':{'c':6}}]
```

and then use the arguments of the keys to grab the nested value for this case `c`. Any thoughts? I was trying to do something like:

```
def compare_something(comparison_list, *args):
    new_list = []
    for something in comparison_list:
        company_list.append(company[arg1?][arg2?])
    return new_list
compare_something(some_list, 'b', 'c')
```

but I'm not too sure how to specify I want the specific order of the arguments where I need them for this. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your expected outcome? What is company_list, where is new_list changed inside your function, what is company? Right now you always return an empty list or am I missing something?

Comment: should be `new_list.append(` thanks trying to just return the values for the nested c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're sure that every item in the list actually has the requisite nested dictionaries

```
for val in comparison_list:
    for a in args:
        val = val[a]
    # Do something with val
```

Comment: You can also traverse the nested dicts [using `reduce`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16300379/748858) -- Though, It's use has fallen a bit out of favor these days...

Answer (score 2):

The repeated unpacking/navigating that is done iteratively in [Brendan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34936700/674064) can also be done with a recursion:

```
some_list = [{'a':1, 'b':{'c':2}}, {'a':3, 'b':{'c':4}}, {'a':5, 'b':{'c':6}}]


def extract(nested_dictionary, *keys):
    """
    return the object found by navigating the nested_dictionary along the keys
    """
    if keys:
        # There are keys left to process.

        # Unpack one level by navigating to the first remaining key:
        unpacked_value = nested_dictionary[keys[0]]

        # The rest of the keys won't be handled in this recursion.
        unprocessed_keys = keys[1:]  # Might be empty, we don't care here.

        # Handle yet unprocessed keys in the next recursion:
        return extract(unpacked_value, *unprocessed_keys)
    else:
        # There are no keys left to process. Return the input object (of this recursion) as-is.
        return nested_dictionary  # Might or might not be a dict at this point, so disregard the name.


def compare_something(comparison_list, *keys):
    """
    for each nested dictionary in comparison_list, return the object
    found by navigating the nested_dictionary along the keys

    I'm not really sure what this has to do with comparisons.
    """
    return [extract(d, *keys) for d in comparison_list]


compare_something(some_list, 'b', 'c')    # returns [2, 4, 6]
```